# Not able to create two GLFW windows at the same time

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I want to share GLFW main window context in another thread so i am trying to share the context of main window.

```cpp
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <thread>


int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;


GLFWwindow *wnd = nullptr;

void wnd2(void)
{
  GLFWwindow *wnd2 = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "window 2", nullptr, wnd);
  if (wnd2 == nullptr)
  {
    std::cout << "New window Not created";
    return;
  }
  else
    std::cout << "New window created";

  glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd2);

// if i create a new window
//GLFWwindow* offscreen_context = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "", NULL, NULL);
//than i am able to create a new window
}

int main()
{
  glfwInit();
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


  // glfw window creation
  // --------------------
  wnd = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

  if (wnd == nullptr)
  {
    std::cout << "window not created" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(0); // have to disable the first to create the second window
  std::thread wnd2thread(wnd2);

      // Even if i try to set the main window context than also the secondary window is not created
  //glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd);
  if (wnd == NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to create the first  GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
  }

  while (true)
  {

  }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

The issue i am facing is that i am only able to create one window only.

I have to disable my main window to create another window in the thread.

Comment: if i create a new window GLFWwindow* offscreen_context = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "", NULL, NULL);

Comment: Than it creates